# How to attach debugger to Wear OS emulator (or watch) and debug a complication provider?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I am trying to debug a Wear OS complication provider, and I cannot find any instructions on how to do so.

I didn't write it, and I'm new to Android development - I'm trying to diagnose a bug in an Open Source project.

I have the phone and watch emulators working (both are Android 11, x86) and paired. The app deploys and runs on both. When I try to debug the Wear OS side, however, a vast majority of the breakpoints aren't being hit (and don't have the little checkbox in Android Studio).

The code for the actual app will debug fine - it hits breakpoints. But the code that provides data for the face and the complication provider won't attach - breakpoints are inactive.

I tried attaching to ALL the processes on the watch at once. I went through them one-by-one. Nothing - none of the processes seem to have the complication provider code in them - or if they do, the debugger can't find it.

I've been banging my head on this for a couple days. According to Google "complication provider" and "attach debugger" do not exist on the same page anywhere on the internet.

Is it simply not possible? It looks like faces can be debugged but it doesn't seem to be working either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So... is nobody using these things? What am I missing??

Comment: The question doesn't make it easy to help.  Is there a link to the open source project?  It should *just* work when you debug an app with a complication and then confiture the watchface to show the complication. But there isn't anything to go on from this report.  Watchfaces and Complications are just regular android apps with services instead of activities.